# How do I make this AJAX Prefilter apply only to GET requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
        options.data = $.param($.extend(originalOptions.data, { browser_url: window.location.pathname }));
    });
```

This is my code. How can I do this only with GET requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test over the `options.type`:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    if(options.type.toUpperCase() === "GET")
        options.data = $.param($.extend(originalOptions.data, { browser_url: window.location.pathname }));
});
```